# Determine the nature of the solution to the PDE $xp+yq+p^2+q^2-u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A solution to the PDE $$xp+yq+p^2+q^2-u=0,$$ where $p=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $q=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, represents

1. an ellipse in the $xy$-plane.
2. an ellipsoid in the $xyu$ plane.
3. a parabola in the $u-x$ plane.
4. a hyperbola in the $u-y$ plane.

Since we can write $u=px+qy+p^2+q^2$ so it is in Clairaut's form and solution is $u(x,y)=ax+by+a^2+b^2$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants. So how can I conclude which option is correct? I have no idea. Please help.